# How do you prove the join of two power sets P(A) and P(B) is a subset to P(A or B)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am supposed to prove that the join of two powersets of every two sets A,B is

P(A) ∪ P(B) ⊆ P(A ∪ B) and that this can happen the  other way around too.

At first i thought that: 
P(A)={S1:S1⊆A} and P(B)={S2:S2⊆B}

P(A) ∪ P(B) ⊆ P(A ∪ B)={x:x∈(P(A) ∪ P(B))→ x∈(A ∪ B)}
={x:x∈(S1 ∪ S2)→ x∈(A ∪ B)} //??

or must i write it like this instead:

P(A) ∪ P(B) ⊆ P(A ∪ B)={S:(S⊆A ∪ S⊆B)→ S⊆(A ∪ B)}

={x:((x∈A→x∈S) ∪ (x∈S→x∈B))→ (x∈S→x∈(A ∪ B))}
and then continue with p → q ≡ ¬p ∨ q..

Is this right? if not what did i understaund wrong and what should i do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your first characterization. Let $S_1 \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. $S_1 \subset A \subset A\cup B$ so $S_1 \in \mathcal{P}(A\cup B)$. Can you show the same for $B$? And from there you can quickly conclude. Do a couple more exercises and you will get the hang of this.

For the example of equality there are a lot of examples. Of course some of them are cheap, i.e. let $A$ and $B$ be the same set. Try constructing examples with small sets.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in P(A) \cup P(B)$. Without loss of generality let $x \in P(A)$. Then $x\subseteq A$ and thus $x\subseteq A \cup B$. That is, $x \in P(A\cup B)$.

For equality, consider $A=B$ or $B=\emptyset$ and $A$ is anything.